Is second-order arithmetic subject to Gödel's first incompleteness theorem? If so, why is it?
I have studied Gödel's first incompleteness theorem for first-order logic (FOL) and believe I grasp the proof. The theorem implies the existence of non-standard models for Peano arithmetic.
I also heard that second-order arithmetic is categorical, meaning that all its models are isomorphic. My question is: Is second-order arithmetic subject to Gödel's first incompleteness theorem? If so, why is it?
To be more specific, I learned from Wiki that there is no deductive system that simultaneously satisfies these three desired attributes:
(Soundness) Every provable second-order sentence is universally valid, i.e., true in all domains under standard semantics.
(Completeness) Every universally valid second-order formula, under standard semantics, is provable.
(Effectiveness) There is a proof-checking algorithm that can correctly decide whether a given sequence of symbols is a proof or not.
So, is it true that second-order logic (SOL) doesn't satisfy the 'effectiveness' condition? If so, are the axioms not effectively checkable, or are the deduction rules not effectively checkable?

First of all, an unfortunate clarification is in order: the phrase "second-order arithmetic" refers to two things, the theory $\mathsf{PA}_2$ of single-sorted (= referring to natural numbers only, not sets of natural numbers) arithmetic formulated in second-order logic (with standard semantics), or a particular two-sorted, first-order theory $\mathsf{Z}_2$ (similarly to how $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is first-order despite being "about" high-type objects). Your question is specifically about $\mathsf{PA}_2$, whereas e.g. the title of Subsystems of second-order arithmetic refers to $\mathsf{Z}_2$. That being out of the way ...

The issue is indeed the inference rules. Since $\mathsf{PA}_2$ is finitely axiomatized, this happens even at the level of tautologies:

The set of second-order validities (= second-order sentences true in every model) is not computably enumerable. In fact, it's not even second-order definable over the natural numbers!

So "the entailment relation is not effective" is massively understating the case. This is an instance of a more general phenomenon:

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a structure which is capable of "coding" (in some appropriate sense) the syntax of a logic $\mathcal{L}$. If there is an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence pinning down $\mathscr{A}$ up to isomorphism, then the $\mathcal{L}$-entailment relation (with respect to the above "coding") is not $\mathcal{L}$-definable in $\mathscr{A}$.

The proof of this is just the proof of Tarski's undefinability theorem, which is really quite general. See e.g. Paulos or Feferman.

Thank you! Can I ask a follow-up question? So the problem is there is no completeness theorem for second-order logic, right? Does a proof-checking system still exist for second-order logic?
